# Как использовать telethon.tl.types.ReactionCustomEmoji

Tags: telethon

хочу сделать скрипт который будет на опеределенное сообщение отправлять кастомное эмодзи с помощью telethon.tl.types.ReactionCustomEmoji
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, или отправьте пример кода